# how to apply pagination on search result from multiple fields using post method and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, mysql, post, pagination

i am new to PHP. i developed a new page which show all result from a table. i also place some filter on top of the page to show search results.after submit the search result, it show filtered result with proper pagination. but when i click on pagination no. 2nd or 3rd page, it again display all the results. i search a lot on stackoverflow sites or other sites but unable to do so. please help to sort this problem. i posted the code here

```
// single page for show result and submit query "allcustomerdetails.php"

<form name="frmnamesd" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" onSubmit="return validated(this)" id = "frmnamesd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset class="row1">
                &nbsp &nbsp; <label>Search By:</label>
                <br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Customer ID:</label> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="c_id" size = "8" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['c_id']) ? $_POST['c_id'] : '';?>" />&nbsp &nbsp;
                <label>Name:</label> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="c_name" size = "10" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['c_name']) ? $_POST['c_name'] : '';?>" /> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <label>Mobile:</label> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="c_mobile" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" size="10" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['c_mobile']) ? $_POST['c_mobile'] : '';?>" /> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <label>Customer Type:</label>&nbsp &nbsp 
                <select name="c_type">              
                    <option value="<?php echo isset($_POST['c_type']) ? $_POST['c_type'] : '';?>" ><?php echo isset($_POST['c_type']) ? $_POST['c_type'] : "-select-";?></option>
                    <option value="IW">IW</option>
                    <option value="AMC">AMC</option>
                    <option value="SAC">SAC</option>
                    <option value="OW">OW</option>
                    <option value="PS">PS</option>
                </select>&nbsp &nbsp;
                <label>Date From/To:</label>&nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="date" name="c_from" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['c_from']) ? $_POST['c_from'] : '';?>">
                <input type="date" name="c_to" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['c_to']) ? $_POST['c_to'] : '';?>" ><br><br>
                &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp;<label>Address:</label> &nbsp &nbsp;&nbsp &nbsp;&nbsp &nbsp;&nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="c_address" size = "32" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['c_address']) ? $_POST['c_address'] : '';?>" > &nbsp &nbsp;
                <center><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp &nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset"></center>
                </fieldset>
                </form>

<?php 

$limit = 100;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 

    $page  = $_GET["page"];
    $page_offset = ($page-1) * $limit; 
} 
else { 
$page_offset = 0;
$page = 1;
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM customer_details";
$querycount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer_details";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // define the list of fields
    $fromdate = $_POST['c_from'];
    $todate  = $_POST['c_to'];
    $fields = array('c_id','c_name','c_mobile', 'c_type','c_address');
    $conditions = array();

    // loop through the defined fields
    foreach($fields as $field){
        //$abc = $_POST[$field];
        //die;
        // if the field is set and not empty
        if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {
            // create a new condition while escaping the value inputed by the user (SQL Injection)
            $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST[$field]) . "%'";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['c_from']) && $_POST['c_to'] != '') {
    // builds the query
            $query .= " WHERE c_next_service between '$fromdate' and '$todate'";
            $querycount .= " WHERE c_next_service between '$fromdate' and '$todate'";

            if(count($conditions) > 0) {

                $query .= " AND" . implode (' AND ', $conditions);
                $querycount .= " AND" . implode (' AND ', $conditions);
                $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit";
                $querycount .= " order by c_id desc";
            }
            else {
                $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit";
                $querycount .= " order by c_id desc";
            }
        }
    // if there are conditions defined
    elseif(count($conditions) > 0) {
            $query .= " WHERE" . implode (' AND ', $conditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
            $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit" ;
            $querycount .= " WHERE" . implode (' AND ', $conditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
            $querycount .= " order by c_id desc" ;
        }
    else {
        // append the conditions
            $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit";
            $querycount .= " order by c_id desc";
        }
    }
else {
    $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit";
    $querycount .= " order by c_id desc";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$resultcount = mysqli_query($con,$querycount);
$count = mysqli_fetch_row($resultcount);  
$totalrows = $count[0];  

<?php if($_POST) {?>
<br><center><button onClick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</button></center>

<?php
    }
$total_pages = ceil($totalrows/$limit);  
$pagLink = "<div class='pagin'>";  
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
                $pagLink .= "<a href='allcustomerdetail.php?page=".$i."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$i."</a>";   
};  
    ?><br><br><center><?php echo $pagLink . "</div>";?><br><br></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

after giving some clue by stackoverflow user, i am able to solve my problem some of the code i posted below:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['msg'])) { ?><center><h5><b><font color="red"><?php echo $_GET['msg'];}?></font></b></h5></center>         
                <h4>All Customers Detail</h4>

                <form name="frmnamesd" method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" onSubmit="return validated(this)" id = "frmnamesd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset class="row1">
                &nbsp &nbsp; <label>Search By:</label>
                <br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>Customer ID:</label> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="c_id" size = "8" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" value = "<?php echo isset($_GET['c_id']) ? $_GET['c_id'] : '';?>" />&nbsp &nbsp;
                <label>Name:</label> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="c_name" size = "10" value = "<?php echo isset($_GET['c_name']) ? $_GET['c_name'] : '';?>" /> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <label>Mobile:</label> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="c_mobile" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" size="10" value = "<?php echo isset($_GET['c_mobile']) ? $_GET['c_mobile'] : '';?>" /> &nbsp &nbsp;
                <label>Customer Type:</label>&nbsp &nbsp 
                <select name="c_type">              
                    <option value="<?php echo isset($_GET['c_type']) ? $_GET['c_type'] : '';?>" ><?php echo isset($_GET['c_type']) ? $_GET['c_type'] : "-select-";?></option>
                    <option value="IW">IW</option>
                    <option value="AMC">AMC</option>
                    <option value="SAC">SAC</option>
                    <option value="OW">OW</option>
                    <option value="PS">PS</option>
                </select>&nbsp &nbsp;
                <label>Date From/To:</label>&nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="date" name="c_from" value = "<?php echo isset($_GET['c_from']) ? $_GET['c_from'] : '';?>">
                <input type="date" name="c_to" value = "<?php echo isset($_GET['c_to']) ? $_GET['c_to'] : '';?>" ><br><br>
                &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp;<label>Address:</label> &nbsp &nbsp;&nbsp &nbsp;&nbsp &nbsp;&nbsp &nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="c_address" size = "32" value = "<?php echo isset($_GET['c_address']) ? $_GET['c_address'] : '';?>" > &nbsp &nbsp;
                <center><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button><a href="allcustomerdetail.php" >Refresh</a></button></center>
                </fieldset>
                </form>

<?php 

$limit = 100;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 

    $page  = $_GET["page"];
    $page_offset = ($page-1) * $limit; 
} 
else { 
$page_offset = 0;
$page = 1;
} 
//echo  $page_offset;
//die;

$query = "SELECT * FROM customer_details";
$querycount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer_details";
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    // define the list of fields
    $fromdate = $_GET['c_from'];
    $todate  = $_GET['c_to'];
    $fields = array('c_id','c_name','c_mobile', 'c_type','c_address');
    $conditions = array();

    // loop through the defined fields
    foreach($fields as $field){
        //$abc = $_GET[$field];
        //die;
        // if the field is set and not empty
        if(isset($_GET[$field]) && $_GET[$field] != '') {
            // create a new condition while escaping the value inputed by the user (SQL Injection)
            $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[$field]) . "%'";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_GET['c_from']) && $_GET['c_to'] != '') {
    // builds the query
            $query .= " WHERE c_next_service between '$fromdate' and '$todate'";
            $querycount .= " WHERE c_next_service between '$fromdate' and '$todate'";

            if(count($conditions) > 0) {

                $query .= " AND" . implode (' AND ', $conditions);
                $querycount .= " AND" . implode (' AND ', $conditions);
                $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit";
                $querycount .= " order by c_id desc";
            }
            else {
                $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit";
                $querycount .= " order by c_id desc";
            }
        }
    // if there are conditions defined
    elseif(count($conditions) > 0) {
            $query .= " WHERE" . implode (' AND ', $conditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
            $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit" ;
            $querycount .= " WHERE" . implode (' AND ', $conditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
            $querycount .= " order by c_id desc" ;
        }
    else {
        // append the conditions
            $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit";
            $querycount .= " order by c_id desc";
        }
    }
else {
    $query .= " order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit";
    $querycount .= " order by c_id desc";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$resultcount = mysqli_query($con,$querycount);
$count = mysqli_fetch_row($resultcount);  
$totalrows = $count[0];
```

using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] i changed POST method to GET method

```
<?php 

$total_pages = ceil($totalrows/$limit);  
$pagLink = "<div class='pagin'>";

if(isset($_GET['submit'])) { ?>
<br><center><button onClick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</button></center>
<?php 
$url = "c_id=".$_GET['c_id']."&c_name=".$_GET['c_name']."&c_mobile=".$_GET['c_mobile']."&c_type=".$_GET['c_type']."&c_from=".$_GET['c_from']."&c_to=".$_GET['c_to']."&c_address=".$_GET['c_address']."&submit=".$_GET['submit'];
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
                $pagLink .= "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?".$url."&page=".$i."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$i."</a>";   
};  
    ?><br><br><center><?php echo $pagLink . "</div>";?><br><br></center>
<?php
 }
 else {

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
                $pagLink .= "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=".$i."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$i."</a>";   
};  
 ?><br><br><center><?php echo $pagLink . "</div>"; }?><br><br></center>
```

work like a charm....

Answer (score 0):

Its because  when you are in second page you doesn't get any post data and your query became `SELECT * FROM customer_details order by c_id desc LIMIT $page_offset, $limit` like this which gives you all records. you should store either all variables or query in session.
Read about session from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: i welcome ur idea. but i am new to PHP. please send an example to store variables by either Session or query....

Comment: @J.S.Bajaj added link in query and update answer please check again it was grammar mistake

Comment: @J.S.Bajaj Glad it worked. You can also visit :  [Ask question | Get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can. Also you can mark as right